# Trying to convert JSON to Java using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am completely new to Java but have experience in other languages. I have the following JSON file that I am trying to bring into a java program.

```
{
    "Progression": [
        {
            "ProgressionName": "An Apple a Day...",
            "Steps": [
                {
                    "StepName": "Collect an Apple",
                    "Type": "COLLECT",
                    "RewardType": "UNLOCK_CRAFTING",
                    "Reward": "minecraft:golden_apple"
                },
                {
                    "StepName": "Craft a Golden Apple",
                    "Type": "CRAFT",
                    "RewardType": "GIVE",
                    "Reward": "minecraft:diamond"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ProgressionName": "Keeps the Dr Away...",
            "Steps": [
                {
                    "StepName": "Collect an Apple",
                    "Type": "COLLECT",
                    "RewardType": "UNLOCK_CRAFTING",
                    "Reward": "minecraft:golden_apple"
                },
                {
                    "StepName": "Craft a Golden Apple",
                    "Type": "CRAFT",
                    "RewardType": "GIVE",
                    "Reward": "minecraft:diamond"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following class that I thought was correct to store the JSON:

```
public class ProgressionData {
    private Progression progresion;

    public class Progression {
        private String ProgressionName;
        private ProgressionSteps Steps;
    }

    public class ProgressionSteps {
        private String StepName;
        private String Type;
        private String RewardType;
        private String Reward;
    }
}
```

This is the call I am using:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
ProgressionData progressiondata = new Gson().fromJson(br, ProgressionData.class);
```

When I debug the code, `progressiondata` is `NULL`. I know I am missing something fundamental, and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Shouldnt `ProgressionSteps` be an array? Oh, and surely you get some sort of errors?

Comment: Same for progression: it's an array in your JSON file.

Comment: And it's not "progression" but "Progression", capital P.

Comment: Before you go any further take 5-10 minutes to study the JSON documentation at json.org.  Especially in Java, people like to make JSON more complicated than it is, so it's important to understand it reasonably well BEFORE you muck around with the likes of GSON.

Comment: @user3324586 I have answered your question below..

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, your base class should look something like the above:

```
public class ProgressionData {
    private Progression[] progresion;

    public class Progression {
        private String ProgressionName;
        private ProgressionSteps[] Steps;

        // Add getters and setters
    }

    public class ProgressionSteps {
        private String StepName;
        private String Type;
        private String RewardType;
        private String Reward;

        // Add getters and setters
    }

    // Add getter and setter for "Progression"
}
```

**Notes:**

- `progression` and `steps` fields are actually `arrays`.
- You need to add `getters` and `setters` methods for your properties.
- You may experience some issues because you are parsing a `Property` (starting with upper-case P) key from your json to a `property` (lower-case p). If you try to change your field to `Property`, the compiler will probably complain because you can't have either a `Class` and a `Field` with the same name. In that case, you must look for some `GSON` parsing options (for ignoring case, for example).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to map an `array of Progression objects` to a `Progression object`,

change from

```
private Progression progresion;
```

to

```
private List<Progression> progresion;
```

or

```
private Progression[] progresion;
```

and the same thing for `Progression Step objects`

also, don't forget create getters/setters for your members or change access modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Your class is wrong since you have JSONArray inside, please try the following:

```
public class ProgressionData {

    private List<Progression> progresion;

    public class Progression {

        private String ProgressionName;
        private List<ProgressionSteps> Steps;

    }

    public class ProgressionSteps {

        private String StepName;
        private String Type;
        private String RewardType;
        private String Reward;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update following things to make it work

- There is a typo in `progresion`, it should be `Progression`. (This might be the primary reason for getting your object as Null, and Name of the variables should match with keys in Json, not classname. You can also use annotation in your POGO class to map the name of the variable with key using `@SerializedName("Progression")`)
- `Progression` is an array
- `Steps` inside `Progression` is an array

Please update your ProgressionData as below.

```
public class ProgressionData {
    @SerializedName("Progression")
    private List<Progression> progression;

    public class Progression {

        private String ProgressionName;
        private List<ProgressionSteps> Steps;

        //Setters and Getters
    }

    public class ProgressionSteps {

        private String StepName;
        private String Type;
        private String RewardType;
        private String Reward;

        //Setters and Getters
    }

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Use below code to parse your json,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
ProgressionData progressiondata = new Gson().fromJson(br, ProgressionData.class);
```